# Can Objectify support embedded entities of the same type like the embedding entity?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, orm, google-cloud-platform, objectify

According to Objectify documentation embedded entities are supported:

> There is a special case when you embed a class which is itself an @Entity:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> class Person {
>     @Id Long id;
> }
>
> @Entity
> class Car {
>     @Id Long id;
>     Person person;
> }
> ```
>
> This will embed the Person entity in the Car entity.

However, when trying to register the following Class with Category-SubCategory(of type Category) relationship:

```
@Entity
class Ctegory{
    @Id String name;
    Category subCategory;
}

ObjectifyService.register(Category.class);
```

I got **StackOverflowError** Exception:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.isGetter(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.getMethodOrFieldType(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectFieldCommon(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectFieldNoSecurityManager(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.unreflectField(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.unreflectGetter(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.FieldProperty.<init>(FieldProperty.java:41)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata.findKeyFields(KeyMetadata.java:77)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata.<init>(KeyMetadata.java:50)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:64)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:49)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.create(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.create(Translators.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:117)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.<init>(ClassPopulator.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:66)
```

So my theory is that this kind of 'recursive' relationship is not supported although it is a valid common use case.

Is it true? or do I miss something here?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues/321)? Looks like this feature is a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks Mangu. Didn't see it but now it all makes sense

Comment: Would you mind if I post this as an answer? For future reference of the community, you can accept it if you wish to.

Comment: Sure. Go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 'recursive' relationship is an enhancement in progress, according to [an issue](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues/321) in the official Github repository for Objectify, so, for now, it's not possible to do it.